# Get a single point programmatically

Tags: chart.js

This should be easy but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.
From within a plugin, how can I refer to a single point of a dataset?

```
const pulsePoint = {
      id: 'pulsePoint',
      afterDraw: chart => {
       var point = chart.???
       point.borderColor = '#ffffff'
       chart.update()
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should access to dataset meta data by `chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex)`. You will get an object which represents the dataset. In the meta object, there is an array property, `data`, which contains all data elements(the points in your case). In each data element there is a object property, `options`, with the options of the element, where you can set the `borderColor`.

```
const pulsePoint = {
  id: 'pulsePoint',
  afterDraw: chart => {
    const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0); // first dataset
    const firstPoint = meta.data[0];
    // Pay attention because it could be a loop. a condition should be set
    if (firstPoint.options.borderColor !== '#ffffff') {  
      firstPoint.options.borderColor = '#ffffff';
      chart.draw(); // better than update for this use case.
    } 
  }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code does not work as expected. It affects all points...

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. Would it be possible to loop through an array of colors changing it any second? I tried adding a `setInterval` function but colors are changing randomly and not every second.